# How to get collected document time MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

In a MongoDB Atlas searchMeta aggregation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

results = my_collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$searchMeta": {
                "index": "MsgAtlasIndex",
                "count": {"type": "total"},
                "compound": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "path": "ts",
                                "gte": datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24),
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "equals": {"path": "st", "value": 2},
                            "equals": {"path": "aff", "value": 2},
                            "equals": {"path": "src", "value": 6},
                        },
                    ]
                },
            }
        }
    ]
)
list(results)
```

Output

```
[{'count': {'total': 38}}]
```

I need to get the time of the latest collected message via `dt` key
Wanted result

```
[{'count': {'total': 38}},
'last_message_datetime': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 16, 11, 30, 21)]
```

I can use this line `"last_message_datetime": {"$max": "$dt"}` in a normal aggregation but how to do it using Atlas?

Sample document below:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64da2904b028a6d62965d623"),
    "ts": datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 14, 13, 15, 48, 632000),
    "dt": datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 14, 13, 14, 58),
    "aff": 2,
    "src": 2,
    "st": 2,
}
```